# Understanding how a hash join works

Tags: postgresql, join, explain

I have the following execution plan for this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM houses INNER JOIN users ON houses.creator_id = users.id;

Hash Join  (cost=16.52..20.79 rows=100 width=600)
  Hash Cond: (houses.creator_id = users.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on houses  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=100 width=348)
  ->  Hash  (cost=12.90..12.90 rows=290 width=252)
        ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..12.90 rows=290 width=252)
```

If I understood the hash join algorithm correctly, what it does is put the right relation (`users`) into a hash table and then find the appropriate rows in the left relation (`houses`) using that fast access hash table.

However, I don't know how this matches with that `EXPLAIN`. Why is it doing a sequential scan on `houses`? I understand that the sequential scan of `users` is to dump all that data into the hash, but why the seq scan on `houses`?

Comment: Why the close? Why is not a legitimate question?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/hash-join-partial-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the second step slightly wrong:

- First, the *inner relation* is scanned and the join condition is hashed. This way, a hash structure is built.
- Second, **the *outer relation* is scanned** and the hash table is probed for matches for each row found.

If the second step were the other way around, you would have a nested loop join with an unnecessary hashing step.